# I want to get a list of object from my calling intent

Tags: android, list, object, android-activity

I have an application calling a second activity using a list of objects. that return the list of objects, my code is following

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();    
                bundle.putSerializable("myList", (Serializable) list);
                returnIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.setResult(100, returnIntent);
                context.finish();
```

And I am trying to retrive that list of objects, but I cannt

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 100) {
        Bundle bundel = data.getExtras();
        try {
            list = (List<Model>) bundel.get("myList");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("MY ERROR", ex.toString());
        }
        Toast.makeText(GetXmlFromUrlActivity.this, "You need to enter your name: " + list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

Can anyone please help me?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use two methods:1. Serializable your List ,your cannot put the list  to  the intent direct
2. you can use static for the  (List as global variable

Answer (score 1):

I just found my answer, I just change my class structure, make it Serializable such,

```
public class Model implements Serializable
```

it works fine for me.

Comment: Serializable is a bit slow you can use Parcelable for Android.